# I'm trying to find the average_months_between two functions and also rounding the number to one decimal point. IN oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE VIEW AVGMNTHSBETWEEN 
AS 
    SELECT 
        VENDOR_NAME, 
        AVG(INVOICE_DUE_DATE, INVOICE_DATE) AS MONTHS_BETWN
    FROM 
        VENDORS 
    INNER JOIN 
        INVOICES ON VENDORS.VENDOR_ID = INVOICES.VENDOR_ID
    GROUP BY 
        VENDOR_NAME
    HAVING 
        AVG(ROUND(CONVERT(DECIMAL(5, 4 (INVOICE_DUE_DATE, INVOICE_DATE)) >= 1.5
    ORDER BY 
        MONTHS_BETWN DESC;
```

I get errors with sorting the result set in descending order by the average_months_between, and the results to only show those vendors that the “average_months_between” is greater than or equal 1.5 months.

Comment: Well for starters, that's not how you take an average.  I think you mean, `AVG(INVOICE_DUE_DATE- INVOICE_DATE)'

Comment: Thanks, how do i get the result set in descending order by the average_months_between, and and the results to only show those vendors that the “average_months_between” is greater than or equal 1.5 months?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions089.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for **months** between, then include that function. If you just subtract two `DATE` datatype values, you'll get number of days between them.

Round result where you selected it (not in the having clause, although you'll probably want to do that as well).

Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW avgmnthsbetween 
  AS 
SELECT 
  vendor_name, 
  ROUND(AVG(months_between(invoice_due_date, invoice_date)), 1) AS avg_months_betwn
FROM vendors INNER JOIN invoices 
                     ON vendors.vendor_id = invoices.vendor_id
GROUP BY 
  vendor_name
HAVING 
  ROUND(AVG(months_between(invoice_due_date, invoice_date)), 1) >= 1.5
ORDER BY avg_months_betwn DESC;
```